# Datadog distinct-like custom metrics

Tags: metrics, datadog

Given following scenario:

- A lambda receives an event via SQS
- The lambda receives a uuid pointing to an entity.
- The lambda may fail with an error
- SQS will retrial that particular entity several times
- The lambda will be called with different entities thousand of times

Right now we monitor a custom error-count metric like `myService.errorType`.
Which gives us an exact number of how many times an error occurred - independent from a specific entity: If an entity can't be processed like 100 times, then the metric value will be `100`.

What I'd like to have, though, is a distinct metric based on the UUID.
Example:

- entity with id 123 fails 10 times
- entity with id 456 succeeds
- entity with id 789 fails 20 times

Then I'd like to have a metric with the value of `2` - because the processes failed for two entities only (and not for 30, as it would be reported right now).

While searching for a solution I found the possibility of using tags. But [as the docs point](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/tagging/) out they are not meant for such a use-case:

> Tags shouldn’t originate from unbounded sources, such as epoch timestamps, user IDs, or request IDs. Doing so may infinitely increase the number of metrics for your organization and impact your billing.

So are there any other possibilities to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it now by verifying the status via code and by adding tags to the metrics:

- `occurrence:first`
- `subsequent`

This way I can filter in my dashboard for `occurrence:first` only.

Comment: Hi @christoper, may I ask how you add that tag? or any reference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make sure things are clear, you have a metric called `myService.errorType` with a tag `entity`. This metric is a counter that will increase every time an entity is in error. You will then use this metric query:

```
sum:myService.errorType{*} by {entity}
```

When you speak about UUID, it seems that the cardinality is small (here you show 3). Which means that every hour you will have small amount of UUID available. In that case, adding UUID to the metric tags is not as critical as user ID, timestamp, etc. which have a limitless number of options.

I would invite you to add this uuid tag, and check the cardinality in the [metric summary page](https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary) to ensure it works.

Then to get the number of UUID concerned by errors, you can use something like:

```
count_not_null(sum:myService.errorType{*} by {uuid})
```

Finally, as an alternative, if the cardinality of UUID can go through the roof, I would invite you to work with logs or work with Christopher's solution which seems to limit the cardinality increase as well.